# Convert model Pytorch->ONNX->NCNN

Tags: python, onnx, ncnn

Trying to run this [example](https://github.com/Qengineering/YoloV8-ncnn-Raspberry-Pi-4) on your custom trained [Yolov8](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics) model.

Field of study I have a model [best.pt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4FB1UcGt9Rorb8VjiLZ0_SD_E9Np_vU/view?usp=share_link)

[ncnn exporting Insturction](https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/wiki/use-ncnn-with-pytorch-or-onnx)

1. I do the export to ONNX format

`pip install ultralytics yolo mode=export model={HOME}/best.pt format=onnx`

2. simplify onnx model

`pip install onnxsim pip install onnxruntime python -m onnxsim {HOME}/best.onnx {HOME}/best-sim.onnx`

Error: `[1]    67272 segmentation fault  python -m onnxsim best.onnx best-sim.onnx`
But I found a [solution](https://github.com/daquexian/onnx-simplifier/issues/187)

3. onnx to ncnn

`onnx2ncnn best-sim.onnx best.param best.bin`

4. I changing a new model path and CLASS_NAME in the example (file yoloV8.cpp)

`yolo.load_param("best.param"); yolo.load_model("best.bin");`

`const char *class_names[] = {"bus", "car", "truck"};`

4. I changing layer name (file yoloV8.cpp). I looked at the structural model https://netron.app/

`ex.extract("output0", out); ... std::vector<int> strides = {32};`

5. Run [Test image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xBVg_0JWnJfjrnhx4zuC5zueQUJVGEM6/view?usp=share_link)

I get house, but in the process of training the model, it is working.